# Translation in opengles

Tags: opengl-es

1. I translate the modelview matrix
   to: `glTranslatef(-camerax, -cameray,
   -cameraz)`
2. rotate the modelview matrix to camera rotation
   `glRotatef(camangle, camrotx,
   camroty, camrotz)`
3. Then i render
   the objects starting here between
   pushmatrix & popmatrix commands.

   Everything working, translating and
   rotating well. Until i try to move
   camera in the rotated modelview
   matrix. I want to translate the
   camera moves toward (int its own
   object space).
4. I added this line into onKeyDown
   method of UP key: `glTranslatef(0f,
   0f, 1f);`

But with this command, the cam moves toward -z axis of modelview matrix, not toward -z axis of its own space.

I could not figure out how to make the object translation in its own toward direction. Can somebody explain me how it shoud be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
posz += (zdif * (float)(Math.cos(Math.toRadians(yrot))));
glTranslatef(0f, 0f, posz);
```

did make the necessary translation.

Answer (score 1):

It's all about multiplication order (as matrix multiplication is not commutative). It makes a big difference do step 4 before or after step 2! One is in screen space, the other is world space.

Comment: `posz += (zdif * (float)(Math.cos(Math.toRadians(yrot))));

glTranslatef(0f, 0f, posz);`

did make the trick. Anyway thanks for your help.